# spring boot profiles not working correctly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, profile

Hello I have a maven spring boot rest project. I want to add dev and prod configurations to it but it is not working.

Under /src/main/resources i created application.yaml, application-dev.yaml and application-prod.yaml

```
# application.yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: prod
```

- 

```
# application-dev.yaml
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
```

- 

```
# application-prod.yaml
server:
  port: 8099
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/WsDb
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
```

in pom.xml i have the following:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
...
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>${postgres.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

when i run the application in Intellij Idea with debug configuration with the command `mvn clean package spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active = prod` it says :

#### Test Phase output

```
The following 1 profile is active: "prod"   
Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.  
Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 164 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.  
Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version   
Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:4348112a-775e-4b78-a5b7-e5bcfdf21761  
HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
```

#### Run phase output

```
No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 116 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http) 
Starting service [Tomcat]
```

Comment: Why do you use maven profiles? Where have you located the application yaml files? Why do you use different files why not a single one? Which SB version are you workging with?

Comment: You need to give a bit more information about where are the `yml` files stored. How do you know Intellij executes the application with the given command line? Do you created a run configuration with it? Maybe the Intellij run configuration doesn't consider the `yml` files because they aren't marked as resources.

Comment: Does springboot support the file ending `yaml`? Did know that. I always use `yml`.

Comment: @Easterwood i renamed the properties files with .yml but i get the same output result

Comment: The yml files aren't recognized by spring-boot. In the test output you can clearly see that even the dev datasource isn't used.

Comment: @Eastwood, indeed the resources folder was not marked as resources root, i did mark it as resources root and tried again but i get the same result

Comment: The extra whitespaces around the `=` in `-Dspring.profiles.active = prod`, is this a mistake or did you use it that way? For me this won't work at the command line.

Comment: Can you remove the `spring.profiles.active` properties from the `pom.xml` to see what's the test output. Maybe the `The following 1 profile is active: "prod" ` is cause by the  maven `prod` profile and not because of the command line arguments. This is only to gather how your project is working.

Comment: @Easterwood i deleted the property from pom.xml and run the mvn clean package -Dspring.profiles.active=prod, At test phase i get active profile prod h2 database loaded and tomcat run on 8080, while at Run phase it says no active profile set, fall back to default tomact run on port 8080 and Hiraki Pool added connection url=jdbc:h2:mem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256314/discussion-between-easterwood-and-velocity).

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved!**  Below is a summary.

There were 2 problems:
**The first Problem** was that the application.yml, application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml were not getting copied into target and therefore had no effect. This was due to a build configuration i added:

```
<resources>
   <resource>
      <directory>/src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
   </resource>
</resources>
```

This caused maven to no being able to find the resource files and therefore throw an Info message:  `INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\src\main\resources`
To solve this problem i had to append with `${project.basedir}` to the path

```
<directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
```

**After all this solution turned out not to be required, see @Easterwood's comments, removing the first / at the beginning of /src/main/resources solves the problem**

```
<directory>src/main/resources</directory>
```

After this change maven could find the resource files and print `[INFO] Copying 3 resources from src\main\resources to target\classes`

**The second problem** was that Tests were run with the profile that was set through the command line with the parameter -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
[image]

while the jar was run with default profile (the one that is set in application.yml through

```
spring:
   profiles: 
      active: dev
```

or the 'default' profile if none was specified in application.yml or the command line.

To solve this problem i had to set an environment variable in the debug configuration.

[image]

This is the same as

[image]

## Update 20.12.2023

i renamed the maven variable spring.profiles.active to activeProfiles

```
<properties>
   <activeProfiles>dev</activeProfiles>
</properties>
```

and the corresponding profile properties setting

```
<profile>
   <id>dev</id>
   <properties>
      <activeProfiles>dev</activeProfiles>
    </properties>
<profile>

<profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <properties>
        <activeProfiles>prod</activeProfiles>
    </properties>
```

now to select the profile i use -P parameter in the debug configuration

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run -Pdev
```

or

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run -Pprod
```

That sets the value of the maven variable activeProfiles accoding to the active profile (dev or prod), which gets replaced in the application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @activeProfiles@
```

also i had to add the h2 database dependency in pom.xml because spring boot is complaining that no driver was found during test phase.

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
         </dependency>
```

Comment: as @Easterwood said ${project.basedir} is not required, removing the first / from /src/main/resources wors the same.

Comment: Using absolute paths always cause errors: `<directory>/src/main/resources</directory>`. It is also a bad practice to configure the default path for resources.

Comment: The `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` command line has no affect at `spring-boot:run` command. As mentioned in the my answer.

Comment: i had to configure the resources filtering because i wanted to link the spring profiles to maven profiles through a maven variable spring: profiles: active = @app.activeProfile@ and thus had to enable resources filtering, but i'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the command line argument `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` has no affect. The spring-boot plugin [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using.overriding-command-line) describes how to activate the profiles.

```bash
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev,local
```

In your project the `prod` profile is activated only because of the property `spring.profiles.active` in the `application.yaml` file. That has lured me onto the wrong ferry.

In the spring documentation there is also an example how to activate the spring profiles with maven profiles.

```xml
<project>
    <properties>
        <app.profiles>local,dev</app.profiles>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <profiles>${app.profiles}</profiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The reason why application.yml was not picked was because i had <resources><resource><directory>/src/main/resources</directory><filtering>true</filtering></resource></resources> under build that's'why it said INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\src\main\resources. Adding ${project.basedir} fixed it <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory> now it says [INFO] Copying 3 resources from src\main\resources to target\classes Tomcat initialized with port 8099

Comment: This could be a reason but did you try the `dev` profile? What is the output in this case?

Comment: Removing the trailing `/` from `<directory>/src/main/resources</directory>` would also work. The `${project.basedir}` won't be necessary in that case.

Comment: Oh, you're right about that, it works indeed, ${project.basedir} was not required :O

Comment: yes, i tried the dev and prod profile it works fine now, like said i only have to use an argument parameter -Dspring.profiles.active to set the profile for Tests and an environment variable SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev to set the profile to executre the jar file